# Rvest html_nodes span once and Xpath

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

I would like to collect parish.name from masstimes.org

I used selector gadget.  The CSS selector 'span' as an XPath is shown below.  Please report any bugs that you find with this converter.  The result is //span

The data I would like to collect is here: `<span once="parish.name" class="">Saint John Chrysostom [Ruthenian]</span>`

I'm not sure what the html_nodes command should look like?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't bother. You can't scrape this website using rvest alone.

Comment: Would you be able to say how to tell how many pages there will be?  How can you loop through them all?

Comment: The query you presented can potentially return 14 pages.  Is there a way to know that?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is required to display the results. So you won't scrape anything with `Rvest`. You should use `RSelenium`. As an alternative you can download the `JSON` loaded in the background to fetch the data.

First, you need to obtain the `lat` and `long` of the city you're looking for. The website uses Arcgis `API` to get them. For example, for New York the `GET` url is :

```
https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?f=json&SingleLine=New%20York,%20NY,%20USA
```

Output :

```
{"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326,"latestWkid":4326},"candidates":[{"address":"New York","location":{"x":-74.007139999999936,"y":40.714550000000031},"score":100,"attributes":{},"extent":{"xmin":-74.257139999999936,"ymin":40.464550000000031,"xmax":-73.757139999999936,"ymax":40.964550000000031}}]}
```

From this output, `lat` is `40.715` (rounded with 3 digits) and long is `-74.007`. Use `GET` and `content` (as text) from `httr` package to load the file in R. And `str_extract` from `stringr` to extract these 2 values.

Example. I'm looking for Paris in France. We modify the URL (add `Paris` and `FRA` into it) to get the `JSON`, then store its content. We extract `lat` and `long`, then construct the URL with `paste0`.

```
data=GET("https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?f=json&SingleLine=Paris,%20FRA")
parse=content(data,as="text")
lat = round(as.numeric(str_extract_all(parse,"\\d+\\.\\d+")[[1]][2]),digits = 3)
long = round(as.numeric(str_extract_all(parse,"\\d+\\.\\d+")[[1]][1]),digits = 3)
paste0("https://apiv4.updateparishdata.org/Churchs/?lat=",lat,"&long=",long,"&pg=1")
```

Output :

```
https://apiv4.updateparishdata.org/Churchs/?lat=48.857&long=2.341&pg=1
```

You can also manually lookup these values with your favorite search engine.

Once you get them, you can construct your request url. Like the following one :

```
https://apiv4.updateparishdata.org/Churchs/?lat=40.091&long=-82.95&pg=1
```

where `lat` and `long` is the value you've found and `pg` the page number (30 results per page).

Load the JSON in R with `jsonlite`(a df is created) and extract the column of interest :

```
library (jsonlite)
mydata <- fromJSON("https://apiv4.updateparishdata.org/Churchs/?lat=40.091&long=-82.95&pg=1")
mydata$name
```

Output :

```
 [1] "Saint John Chrysostom [Ruthenian]"   "Saint Elizabeth"                    
 [3] "Saint Anthony"                       "St. Matthias"                       
 [5] "Saint Paul"                          "Holy Resurrection [Melkite]"        
 [7] "St. Michael"                         "St. James the Less"                 
 [9] "Our Lady of Peace"                   "Immaculate Conception"              
[11] "Saints Augustine and Gabriel"        "Saint Peter"                        
[13] "Holy Name"                           "Saint Timothy"                      
[15] "Ohio Dominican University"           "St. Thomas More Newman Center"      
[17] "Church of the Resurrection"          "Saint Andrew Roman Catholic Church "
[19] "Saint Matthew"                       "Saint Joan of Arc Catholic Church"  
[21] "St. Thomas the Apostle"              "St. Agatha"                         
[23] "Sacred Heart Church"                 "Saint Dominic"                      
[25] "Saint John the Baptist "             "Saint Francis of Assisi"            
[27] "Saint Patrick"                       "Holy Spirit"                        
[29] "Saint Brendan"                       "Saint Christopher"
```